# When can I leave the absolute value from Chebyshev's inequality?

Tags: probability, random-variables

I have a positive random variable whose distribution is unknown, but its mean is $10$.

I have to find an estimation of its variance, given that $Pr(X\ge9$)=0.9980

I thought of Chebyshev's inequality:

$Pr(|X-10|\geq -1)\leq\frac{D^2X}{1}=0.9980$

But can I leave the absolute value?

Comment: If the question wants an _estimate_, could it be they want you to assume e.g. normal distribution?  (If the question had asked for a _bound_, that's very different, and I'm not sure it's possible anyway.)

Comment: The probability that $|X-10|>-1$ is $1$.

Comment: I'm voting to close because I don't see any reasonable interpretation of what it means to "leave out the absolute value" in Chebyshev's inequality. If you did that, you'd just get a different inequality, which would bear more or less relation to Chebyshev depending on the situation. Perhaps OP could restrict the question to this specific situation and put their finger more precisely on what they want to know.

Comment: Yes, the Question statement is confused.  Possibly it is a garbled form of a problem concerning one-sided tail estimation in contrast to two-sided tails.  But without clarification I don't see what Readers can reasonably do with this Question.